# Convert this "2020-10-19T12:19:04+0530" String to Date or DateTime

Tags: sql-server

How to convert this `"2020-10-19T12:19:04+0530"` string to `Date` or `DateTime` in SQL Server? I'm getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

Comment: Try the [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: The best solution is usually to prevent sending such a string to the database in the first place. Converting from/to strings should be done as far up the stack (as close to the user/outside world) as possible and then *more appropriate* datatypes can be used everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK but I have already tried the solution mentioned in the offical doc but did not work.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever that makes sense. So I will parse it before inserting.

Comment: try to cast it to `datetime2(7)` or - in your case and to stick with datetime - try `CAST(CAST(@x AS datetime2(7)) AS DATETIME)` where `@x` is your date string.

Comment: @Tyron78 Thanks, I tried what you said but i am getting same error

Comment: Hint: `SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2020-10-19T12:19:04+05:30')`, note the `:` in the datetimeoffset.

Comment: @PragatDeshpande ah, I see where the problem is: the time offset needs a column in the middle - the string should end with `+05:30` instead `+0530`.

Comment: @PragatDeshpande if you don't have the possibility of changing the input, you can try to add the column: `SELECT CAST(CAST(LEFT(@x,LEN(@x)-2) + ':' + RIGHT(@x, 2) AS datetime2(7)) AS DATETIME)`

Comment: Are you sure you want `DateTime` and not `DateTimeOffset`? Note that `DateTimeOffset` is the only data type in SQL Server that is time-zone-offset aware...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my comment as answer, since it solved your problem:

If you don't have the possibility of changing the input, you can try to add the column to your date-string:

`SELECT CAST(CAST(LEFT(@x,LEN(@x)-2) + ':' + RIGHT(@x, 2) AS datetimeoffset) AS DATETIME)`

Comment: It works, yes, does it work as expected... may be not.

Comment: @SalmanA according to a comment by the OP under the original post which has for some unknown reason been removed it worked as the OP expected and his problem was solved. Where do you see a problem / bug in this answer?

Comment: it ignores timezone offset part (0530). OP did not mention if it should be ignored or converted; or may be he doesn't know.

Comment: @SalmanA I don't think, that it ignores the timezone: datetime2 is capable of dealing with timezones.

Comment: @SalmanA oh, OK. I modified the answer accordingly. But at least with the given example, the result of datetime2 and datetimeoffset is the same

Answer (score 0):

You may try to convert the input string to `datetimeoffset` data type using one of the [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetimeoffset) string literal formats for datetimeoffset (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm`). But, in your specific case, you need to add `:` in the dateimeoffset part of the input text:

```
DECLARE @datetime varchar(25) = '2020-10-19T12:19:04+0530'
SELECT CONVERT(
   datetimeoffset(0), 
   LEFT(@datetime, LEN(@datetime) - 2) + ':' + RIGHT(@datetime, 2)
)
```

As a side note, using `datetimeoffset` data type is probably a better option, because the input string literal contains information about the time zone. After that you can [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#converting-datetimeoffset-data-type-to-other-date-and-time-types) this value to other date and time data types.

```
DECLARE @datetime varchar(25) = '2020-10-19T12:19:04+0530'
SELECT CONVERT(
   datetime,
   CONVERT(
      datetimeoffset(0), 
      LEFT(@datetime, LEN(@datetime) - 2) + ':' + RIGHT(@datetime, 2)
   )
)
```

Of course, you can get only the datetime part of the input string and convert it to `datetime` data type:

```
DECLARE @datetime varchar(25) = '2020-10-19T12:19:04+0530'
SELECT CONVERT(
   datetime, 
   LEFT(@datetime, 19)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StringDate VARCHAR(40) = '2020-10-19T12:19:04+0530'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,STUFF(@StringDate,23,0,':')) -- RESULT 2020-10-19 12:19:04.0000000

SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME2,STUFF(@StringDate,23,0,':')), 101) --RESULT 10/19/2020
```

Try now what you want.

Below site helps you to format date.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/